# Get data from MS Access and insert into Oracle SQL

Tags: python, oracle, ms-access

I'm creating a Python code that retrieves data from an MS Access table and inserts it into an Oracle SQL table, but I'm having problems with the *execute* function of the Oracle cursor when using INSERT INTO statement.

When I run the code, the following error appears: **function takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)**
Apparently the error is in *row[0]...* part. But I don't know what to do to solve it.

this is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import cx_Oracle

# Set up the Microsoft Access connection
access_conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\MyFolder\ACC_BASE.MDB;'
    )
access_conn = pyodbc.connect(access_conn_str)

# Define the Oracle SQL connection string
oracle_conn_str = cx_Oracle.makedsn("MyConnection", "MyPort", "MySID")

# Create a connection to the Oracle SQL database
oracle_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="MyUser", password="MyPassword", dsn=oracle_conn_str)

# Create a cursor for each connection
access_cursor = access_conn.cursor()
oracle_cursor = oracle_conn.cursor()

# Execute the select statement to extract data from the Access table
access_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ACC_TABLE')

# Loop through the rows of the Access table and insert them into the Oracle SQL table
for row in access_cursor.fetchall():
    oracle_cursor.execute(
        'INSERT INTO ORACLE_TABLE (COD, LEV, AZET, HUES) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
        row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
    )

# Commit the changes to the Oracle SQL table
oracle_conn.commit()

# Close the cursors and connections
access_cursor.close()
access_conn.close()
oracle_cursor.close()
oracle_conn.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ORA-01036 illegal variable name/number" at INSERT INTO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75772652/ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-at-insert-into-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.execute()` method takes two arguments. You've supplied 5. The second argument should be a LIST containing your parameters:

```
oracle_cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO ORACLE_TABLE (COD, LEV, AZET, HUES) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
    [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]]
)
```

Comment: Since '?' isn't usable in Oracle, this solution won't work.  Oracle bind variables are represented by names like ":1", or ":myname".  A solution is given in the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75772652/ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-at-insert-into-query/75773519#75773519